# Caching module / Caching in Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, caching, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I am using Orchard 1.7.3 and there is certain code in my project that I don't want to cache.
Is there any way to use the ICacheManager in orchard to exclude certain part of my code from caching?

Or is there some setting in the Orchard's Caching module that will exclude certain content from caching?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can decorate controller actions with the `[OutputCache(Duration = 0)]` attribute.

There is also a settings page for the output cache where you can specify a list of excluded URLs.

Comment: Can this attribute be applied on Custom Shapes?
I have some code that is used to render data, i don't want this code to be cached. 
The way I am rendering my custom shape is calling @Display.MyShapeName() in a view file. This invokes a function named 'MyShapeName' marked with 'Shape' attribute.